# How to mock a GraphQL type in Rails engine rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, graphql, rails-engines

I'm working inside a Rails engine where I have a GraphQL type.

```
module RailsEngine
  module Graph
    module RailsEngine
      module Types
        MyClass = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
          # some working code here

          field :user, RailsEngine.graph_user_type.constantize, 'The description of user'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`graph_user_type` is a method that I define in the `mattr_accessor` and am getting a specific class of User from the main Rails app through the initializer.

When I'm running my Rspec tests for this type, I'm getting an error `NameError: uninitialized constant Graph`

So I was thinking of mocking the whole line `field :user, RailsEngine.graph_user_type.constantize, 'The description of user'` like this:

```
  before do
    user_type = double('Graph::User::Types::User')
    allow(described_class.fields['user']).to receive(:constantize).and_return(user_type)
  end
```

I've also tried `allow(described_class.fields['user']).to receive(:type).and_return(user_type)` also to no avail!

But I'm still getting the same error! Any ideas?

````
Failure/Error: field :user, RailsEngine.graph_user_type.constantize, 'The description of user'

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Graph```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was hidden here

> graph_user_type is a method that I define in the mattr_accessor and am getting a specific class of User from the main Rails app through the initializer.

Since I was getting the method `graph_user_type` through the initializer to the engine from the main app, before the spec was loaded, the error was already thrown - so it was useless to mock it inside the spec.

The solution was to add the very same thing that the main app initializer had to the dummy initializer inside the engine (with an indication that the data is mocked)

This was my initializer:
`RailsEngine.graph_user_type = 'Graph::User::Types::User'`

This was my dummy initializer inside Engine:
`RailsEngine.graph_user_type = 'MockUserType'`

Answer (score 1):

```
before do
  user_type = double('Graph::User::Types::User')
  allow(described_class.fields['user']).to receive(:constantize).and_return(user_type)
end
```

You need to understand what `allow` method does. It takes an object, on which later expectation is set with `.to receive(...)`.

What seems to have more sense, would be:

```
allow(RailsEngine).to receive(:graph_user_type).and_return('Graph::User::Types::User')
```

or, if you need it to return a double, you'd do sth like

```
allow(RailsEngine).to receive_message_chain('graph_user_type.constantize').and_return(user_type)
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains

This way you're controlling what `RailsEngine.graph_user_type` is returning, and being passed on `field` as a second argument.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion Grzegorz! To fix the issue - I needed to zoom out even more.

Comment: So none of the suggested fixes worked? How odd. What was happening when you tried it?

Comment: They didn't work, unfortunately. I was getting the very same error.
And the reason being it that the method required in the Rails app initializer was requested and not being found even before the test file was loaded, so the mocks wouldn't kick in at this point. 
You solution, however, was really helpful and pointed me to the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Ah! Right, I didn't see it. The `RailsEngine.graph_user_type.constantize` is being used during initialization. Glad I could have helped a bit :)